# Skip outputting the main HTML if redirected

Tags: php, performance, optimization, redirect

On the main `index.php` file, I'm redirecting the user if he is using a mobile phone. But after sending the `Location` header, the rest of the HTML would also be sent to the user, unnecessarily. Is there a way to prevent that and skip sending the normal HTML?

The code looks like this:

```
<?php

if(preg_match(...)){
  header('Location: http://m.mysite.com/');
}

?>

<html>
...normal version of the website...
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always `exit;` after a header( 'Location' ), so the action doesn't continue. That should solve your issue.